# High udpclient cpu use

Tags: c#, task, asyncsocket, udpclient, dataflow

So I have a bunch of different ports I want to listen on and the iterate over the available data to send to a Dataflow pipeline. In total I'm listening on 14 ports. 
Looking for any advice on how to reduce the cpu usage of the following code.

So I'm just passing in the ports to a method then adding them to a list

```
   public static void AddPorts(Dictionary<int,string> ports)
    {
        try
        {


                var NewEndPoints = new List<IPEndPoint>();
                foreach (var port in ports)
                {
                    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port.Key);
                    NewEndPoints.Add(endpoint);
                    if (!Endpoints.Contains(endpoint))
                    {                            
                        Endpoints.Add(endpoint);
                        var client = new UdpClient(endpoint);
                        logger.Info("New Client added on port: {0}", endpoint.Port);
                        Clients.Add(client);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (IgnoredPorts.Contains(endpoint.Port))
                        {
                            logger.Info("Existing client enabled on port: {0}", endpoint.Port);
                            IgnoredPorts.Remove(port.Key);
                        }
                    }
                }
                var differences = Endpoints.Except(NewEndPoints);
                differences.ToList().ForEach(d =>
                {                         
                    if (!IgnoredPorts.Contains(d.Port))
                    {
                        IgnoredPorts.Add(d.Port);
                        logger.Info("Client removed on port: {0}", d.Port);
                    }
                });



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error("Error creating udpclients", ex);
        } 
    }
```

I then iterate over any available data

```
 Task.Run(async delegate
        {

            while (Receive)
            {
                try
                {
                    // get any channels that have data availble
                    // Iterate over the the channels and send to Dataflow pipeline
                    var readyChannels =
                (from channel in Clients
                 where channel.Available > 0 && !ListenersDF.IgnoredPorts.Contains(((IPEndPoint)channel.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port)
                 select channel);

                    // Iterate over the the channels and send to Dataflow pipeline
                    foreach (var channel in readyChannels)
                    {
                        // await on the result of the task
                        await ReceiveAndRespond(channel);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.Error("Error sending packet to bufferBlock", ex);
                }
            }
        });
```

And finally send it to the dataflow pipline

```
async Task ReceiveAndRespond(UdpClient channel)
    {
        UdpReceiveResult? result = null;

        try
        {
            result = await channel.ReceiveAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            logger.Error("Error receiving from channel: " + exc.Message, exc);
        }

        if (result != null)
        {
            var device = (from d in Ports
                          where d.Key == ((IPEndPoint)channel.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port
                          select d.Value).FirstOrDefault();
            UdpData data = new UdpData() { Client = channel, Data = result.Value.Buffer, LocalPort = ((IPEndPoint)channel.Client.LocalEndPoint).Port, LocalIP = ((IPEndPoint)channel.Client.LocalEndPoint).Address, RemoteEndpoint = result.Value.RemoteEndPoint, Device = device };
            Flow.bufferBlock.Post(data);

            // for testing logs the hex string to a log file              
            //logger.Warn(string.Format("Data received on port: {0} for device: {1} with data: {2}", data.LocalPort, data.Device, data.Data.ByteArrayToHexString()));              
        }
    }
```

Then cpu sits at 50% with hardly and traffic and I'm sure there is something messed up about how I'm doing this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the loop `while (Receive)`,  you check and check and check  `where channel.Available > 0` , Considering the speed of the CPU, you mostly check without doing nothing.

Comment: Any better way to get data from channels with data ready to be received?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should change your design. Here is a sample server code.

```
public class UDPServer
{
    public UDPServer(IEnumerable<int> listenPorts)
    {
        foreach(var port in listenPorts)
        {
            var udpClient = new System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient();
            udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            udpClient.BeginReceive(Receive, udpClient);
        }
    }

    public void Receive(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var udpClient = ar.AsyncState as UdpClient;
        IPEndPoint endPoint = null;
        var data = udpClient.EndReceive(ar, ref endPoint);

        //Do some work and send a response back
        var dataToSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(String.Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data).Reverse()));
        udpClient.Client.SendTo(dataToSend, endPoint);

        udpClient.BeginReceive(Receive, udpClient);
    }
}
```

Now, you can test it like this:

```
var server = new UDPServer(new[] { 10000, 10001, 10002 });
await Task.Delay(2000); //Just to keep the code simple, for now.

var udpClient = new UdpClient();
udpClient.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 10001));

while (true)
{
    var line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line == ".") break;

    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
    udpClient.Send(data, data.Length);

    IPEndPoint endPoint = null;
    var recvData = udpClient.Receive(ref endPoint);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvData));
}
```

Comment: What is the value of the UDPServer? Your not using in the test? I see where you going with this. I'm just now sure how to continuously loop over the UDPServer clients and get the result for processing with this design.

Comment: Have you tried to test it? I spent my time and prepared **a working code**. Just create a console app and copy&paste. Are you too busy?

Comment: As Metallica says,  `“Arrogance and ignorance go hand in hand.”`

Comment: Wow , dude. Was a simple question no need to go all flame mode. Either way the original code performs better than this. My thanks for the code example.